# Mailer Error SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php

I need help i keep getting this error,
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Here's my code

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('sendtomail@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you enabled the `smtp` and the `port` in your php.ini?

Comment: I am not sure but I did configure php.ini 
SMTP = mail.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587

and sendmail.ini

smtp_server=smpt.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct except few things. I edited your code and the message get sent. Also check whether your username and password is correct or not as I tried with my username and password.And also check did you include the class.phpmailer.php.

```
<?php
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                   // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('sendtomail@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Ms. Aarju Mishra, after applying your code to mine a new error occured.. which is this:
2016-04-20 07:13:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2016-04-20 07:13:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2016-04-20 07:13:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2016-04-20 07:13:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2016-04-20 07:13:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: bm92b2hvdGVsb3Jtb2NAZ21haWwuY29t 2016-04-20 07:13:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: bm92b2hvdGVs 2016-04-20 07:13:52 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.

Comment: IT means your username and password is not correct.

Comment: Create a new email id in gmail and give that as username and write the password. When I tried to run your code after editing it throws the same error and when I provide correct username and password then the message sent

Comment: Hey did you cheked??

Comment: I had successfully sent the mail. I am really thankful for your help Ms. Aarju Mishra ^_^